# TFS - How can I sort an iteration by column?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to sort iteration work items by 'Assigned To'. I cannot because there are hierarchical items. TFS's [official workaround](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs-boards-plans#display-hierarchy) is to break all parent-child links, thereby flattening the tree to a list. That's not OK- parent-child relationships are important in other contexts.

Is there a way to sort by 'Assigned To' that doesn't require breaking parent-child links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backlog is sorted by priority/importance i.e. work at the top needs to be done before the work at the bottom.

You can create a custom query and filter on the sprint/iteration that you want to see and then sort by Assigned To.

Comment: Yes, a backlog is sorted by priority. An iteration isn't though. In the original text, it says 'iteration', not backlog.

Comment: Oh, but my title says 'backlog'. I see.

Comment: I tried your query suggestion and that will suffice. I suspect you are going to say an iteration is-a backlog and therefore can't be sorted. If that's true, it is an unfortunate implementation choice.

Comment: Where I work, we have two backlogs: a product backlog (the ultimate to-do list for your product) and a sprint/iteration backlog (work that was committed to completing in the next timebox).